# How do I declare a debug only statement

Tags: objective-c, xcode

In C# I can use the following code to have code which only executes during debug build, how can I do the same in Xcode?

```
#if DEBUG
{
    // etc etc
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The NDEBUG symbol should be defined for you already in release mode builds

```
#ifndef NDEBUG
/* Debug only code */    
#endif
```

By using NDEBUG you just avoid having to specify a -D DEBUG argument to the compiler yourself for the debug builds

Comment: but you still have to _add_ NDEBUG to the compiler settings to use release mode.  Many programmers prefer #ifdef DEBUG to the double-negative that's in #ifndef NDEBUG

Comment: I get that many people prefer it but NDEBUG for release is the C standard. By adhering to it you will save yourself trouble. NEDBUG should also be defined for you already in the Xcode release builds

Comment: My apologies XCode doesn't appear to define it by default. 
here's where you should go to add it in: http://developer.apple.com/tools/xcode/xcodebuildsettings.html

Comment: p.s. what if he wants to decouple the behaviour of assert() from his own debugging code?

Comment: Absolutely if he wishes to take control himself he will need to make a concious decision and define accordingly. This appears to be the rationale of the XCode implementers in not providing some default definitions in the way VS and others do. I simply though that he should start with the standard.

Answer (score 71):

You can use

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    ....
#endif
```

You'll need to add `DEBUG=1` to the project's preprocessor symbol definitions in the Debug configuration's settings as that's not done for you automatically by Xcode.

I personally prefer doing `DEBUG=1` over checking for `NDEBUG=0`, since the latter implies that the default build configuration is with debug information which you then have to explicitly turn off, whereas 'DEBUG=1' implies *turning on* debug only code.

Comment: Yup, looks like this is defined by default now -- I just created a standard iOS project in Xcode, and got DEBUG=1 preset in the Preprocessor Macros/Debug section of the project build settings.

Answer (score 15):

DEBUG is now defined in "debug mode" by default under Project/Preprocessor Macros. So testing it always works unless you have a very old project.

However I hate the fact that it messes up the code indentation and not particularly compact. That is why I use another macro which makes life easier.

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define DEBUGMODE YES
#else
#define DEBUGMODE NO
#endif
```

So testing the DEBUGMODE value is much more compact:

```
if (DEBUGMODE) {
//do this
} else {
//do that
}
```

My favourite:

```
NSTimeInterval updateInterval = DEBUGMODE?60:3600;
```

Answer (score 5):

There is a very useful debugging technote: Technical Note TN2124 Mac OS X Debugging Magic
http://developer.apple.com/technotes/tn2004/tn2124.html#SECENV which contains lots of useful stuff for debugging your apps.

Tony