# Hide in-app purchase while being reviewed by Apple

Tags: ios, app-store, in-app-purchase

I have an iPhone app with an in-app purchase and I want to be able to release the app independently from it (the in-app purchase). In other words, there could be times where the in-app purchase is "waiting for review" state and shouldn't be displayed by the app.

If I understand correctly, in this situation, the `SKProductsResponse` object (returned by the Apple App Store in response to a request for information about a list of products) will have the particular product listed under the `invalidProductIdentifiers` array. Thus, before displaying the in-app purchase, I could inspect the array to check for the existence of the product. This should still allow Apple to test the in-app purchase with the released version of my app since I assume their testing is done in a sandbox where all the in-app purchases are valid.

Is this correct? Should I follow a different approach?

Comment: Wouldn't Apple be your best source of information about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You describe the proper workflow for displaying IAP content to the user. Put up a modal dialog or a UIActivityIndicator telling the customer that IAP content is being downloaded. Use the productIdentifiers that are returned to populate your store gui.

I discourage you from hard coding in a specific view for a specific in app purchase, and then attempting to populate that view.  You can do that if you're smart about it and check for valid content ahead of time, but checking after the customer is already expecting to see something can end with both Apple review and your customer thinking your app is broken.

The least pretty implementation would be a tableView displaying the returned productIdentifiers and their respective prices, allowing the customer to pick from a familiar list.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I see that the app does use the activity indicator while getting the data from the App Store but at the same time there is some hardcoded string :( Anyhow, obviously there is not way to test this scenario? What I mean is can I run the app outside of the sandbox? If I can't, I will need to modify the code to induce this condition and hopping that will work once is released...

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by testing it outside the sandbox. If you're asking if the IAP can be released to the world before Apple has a chance to review it, the answer is no.

Comment: Because, when I test the app, it always talks to the sandbox instead of to the Apple Store, the IAP will be "valid" therefore I can't really verify that the code I use to filter out the invalid IAP really works unless I induce this condition with code (which is what I ended up doing). I'm thinking that if there was a way to build the app so that it talks to the Apple Store instead to the sandbox, I could test it without modifying the code before running the test. Anyhow, thank you for your answers..really help!

Comment: Ok, it makes a lot of sense now! You should use a compiler flag to see if you're using a debug build vs release build http://stackoverflow.com/questions/479531/how-do-i-declare-a-debug-only-statement You'll only be in Sandbox when you're in DEBUG.